# NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler not working on Lion 10.7.3

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsexception

The following simple code on the app's delegate on a new cocoa test project.

```
void onUncaughtException(NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"Caught!!! %@", exception);
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&onUncaughtException);

    NSException *exception = [[NSException alloc]initWithName:@"exception" reason:@"exception reason here" userInfo:nil];
    @throw exception;
}
```

I only get single console log line with the exception name and reason, but onUncaughtException does not get called. The app continues to run without a problem.

What am I missing here?  I tried this on debug and release builds with same results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the ins and outs of it, but I suspect that NSApplication is intercepting it before it fails through to your handler.

Comment: Yes, exceptions on the main thread of an app are not uncaught. @theReverend, see [Exception Programming Topics: Controlling a Program’s Response to Exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/ControllingAppResponse.html).